# How to specify fixed parameter on hibernate join mapping?

Tags: java, hibernate, mapping

I have the following case, where I have two classes/tables:

```
public class Parent {
    @Id
    @Column(name="parent_id")
    private Integer parentId;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="child_id") //Notice here that i only specified one of the two id columns of the Child class
    private Child child;
    ...
}

public class Child {
    @Id
    @Column(name="child_id")
    private Integer childId;

    @Id
    @Column(name="alive")
    private Boolean alive;

    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;
}
```

As you can see, `child` has two primary keys, which means i can have the same `child_id` in two rows, one with `alive=true` and another with `alive=false`, but i don't have the `alive` attribute on the parent:

```
PARENT TABLE
parent_id | child_id
--------------------
500       | 1

CHILD TABLE
child_id | alive | name
--------------------------
1        | TRUE  | DONALD
1        | FALSE | HILLARY
```

I want hibernate to generate the join clause inserting the `alive` attribute, only when `alive=true`, for example:

```
select * from Parent inner join Child on Child.child_id=Parent.child_id and Child.alive=true
```

Is there a way to do this, so when i execute a query like `select p from Parent p` it executes the query as expected?

Comment: What do you mean ` inserting the alive attribute, only when alive=true`? Isn't `alive` populated already when searching by `alive=true`?

Comment: What i mean is, if i run a HQL query like `select p from Parent p` the sql generated by hibernate will not include the `alive` attribute in the join section (as it should be because i didn't include any mapping of the `alive` attribute when i specified the `@JoinColumn` on the `Parent` class), for example: `...from Parent p inner join Child c on c.child_id = p.child_id`. What i want is hibernate to generate the SQL query with the `alive=true` in the join section.

Comment: For the Parent class you can use @JoinColumnOrFormula(formula=@JoinFormula(value="(SELECT a.id FROM Child c WHERE c.childd_id= child_id and alive=true)", referencedColumnName="child_id")

Comment: @StanislavL thanks, `@JoinFormula` did the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the Parent class you can use

```
@JoinColumnOrFormula(formula=@JoinFormula(value="(SELECT a.id 
                                                  FROM Child c 
                                                  WHERE c.child_id=child_id 
                                                  and alive=true)", 
   referencedColumnName="child_id")
```

Posted correct comment as an answer